# Why do I get a Warning that "git lfs clone is deprecated"?

Tags: git, deprecated, git-lfs

When I run this:

```
git lfs clone https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/FPSSample.git
```

I get this message:

> WARNING: 'git lfs clone' is deprecated and will not be updated with new flags from 'git clone'
> 'git clone' has been updated in upstream Git to have comparable
> speeds to 'git lfs clone'.

What does this mean, and what do I need to do about it?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking or what your answer is intended to convey, but https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/pull/2526 explains what's going on.

Comment: It's not at all clear why you sprinkled five tags into this, none of them [tag:git-lfs], when this has nothing to do with C#, plain Git, Unity3d, or Linux-From-Scratch (LFS here is Large File Storage and is an add-on for plain Git, not part of basic Git).

Comment: It is telling you you should simply use `git clone` instead as in new versions it automatically also downloads the LFS linked objects (assuming LFS is installed on your device)

Comment: @derHugo That sounds like it would make a good answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: oh it has a relation, that i was tryna clone the FPS kit from unity 3D which is written in c#

Comment: @derHugo that was the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 8):

It is simply telling you that `git lfs clone` is [deprecated](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/pull/2526) and you should only use

```
git clone
```

instead as in newer `git` versions it automatically also downloads the LFS linked objects assuming LFS is installed on your device.

If you never did before it should be enough to once run

```
git lfs install --skip-repo
```

somewhere on your machine and then `git clone`